# Why is the DNS for my 6-month old domain suddenly not resolving?

Tags: dns

The domain is http://epochchartjs.com, or http://www.epochchartjs.com

Whois says it's still active, and the nameservers match what's in Zerigo, http://whois.domaintools.com/epochchartjs.com

However, it doesn't load in the browser, and `host epochchartjs.com` yields:

```
$ host www.epochchartjs.com
Host www.epochchartjs.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dig epochchartjs.com NS` yields no NameSevers. Please verify with the reseller/registrar with whom you have purchased the domain. They must add the NS records for this domain.

Comment: Just resubmitted them. Going to see if that fixes them.